# Possible to generate an iPhone application automatically from another iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, code-generation

As title; is there any function that can achieve this?

Comment: Please rephrase your question more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically maybe, practically no. If you want to sell it in the App store double no.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, no. Official apps must be compiled and signed on an OS X machine.

In practice, sort of - if you don't mind jailbreaking. For jailbroken phones, gcc and signing tools are available that run on the iPhone. So on jailbroken phones you could have an application that generated new applications. Apple wouldn't let you sell such an app in the App Store, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [this link](http://jerakeen.org/notes/2008/11/iphone-local-web-applications/) which quotes the SDK in saying:

> 3.3.2. [..] No interpreted code may be downloaded and used in an Application
>   except for code that is interpreted
>   and run by Apple’s Published APIs and
>   built-in interpreter(s).

and

> 3.3.3 Without Apple’s prior written approval, an Application may not
>   provide, unlock or enable additional
>   features or functionality through
>   distribution mechanisms other than the
>   App Store.

between those two restrictions I think it would be practically impossible to dynamically create any kind of application on the fly (with the possible exception of the pure JavaScript/HTML app concept mentioned in the article).

Answer (score 0):

If your iPhone is jailbroken, install "CallMe" from Cydia.
That does exactly what you want: It generates small applications with the icon of a contact, and if you launch one of those small apps, that'll launch the phone app and call the phone number of the contact.